# Rails SystemStackError (stack level too deep) in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stack-overflow

I have a simple controller doing a search on the Twitter. My search works fine from the rails console, but I'm getting a stack overflow error when I run this and can't figure out what's going on. My log file shows the index method running over and over.

```
Controller 

class TimelinesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @timelines = Twitter.search("Ford Edge", :rpp => 3, :result_type => "recent")
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @timelines }
    end
  end
end

View

<% @timelines.each do |timeline| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= timeline.from_user %></td>
    <td><%= timeline.text %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Appreciate any thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code that requests the TimelinesController#index action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the offending line: `format.html index.html.erb`

`index.html.erb` is not in quotes so it looks like a sequence of method calls to ruby, The first of which is `index`, which is causing the infinite recursion.

Rails should render the right template for you when you call `format.html` without an argument, and if not, make sure to wrap the template name in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I removed the entire respond_to block and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

@timelines.**results**.each{...

;)